# Why does an exponential random graph model belong to the exponential family?

Tags: statistics, graph-theory

The exponential random graph model is defined as,
$$ P_\theta(Y=y)=\frac{\exp\{\theta^ts(y)\}}{c(\theta)}.$$
Where $y \in \mathcal{Y}$ the set of all possible networks, $\theta = (\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_s)^t$ is a vector of parameters, $s(y)$ contains the network information (eg. numbers of edges, triangles etc.) and $c(\theta)$ is the normalization factor.

I can't seem to figure out why this distribution belongs to the exponential family of distributions as I need to say something about the density function and not the distribution.

To clarify the density function $p_\theta(y) = p(y|\theta)$ of $P_\theta(Y=y)$ needs to be written as:
$$
p_\theta = h(y)\exp \left\{ \eta(\theta)^tT(y) - A(\theta)\right\}.
$$
Could anyone help me with figuring out why the density can be written as an exponential family?

Comment: I think my question was misunderstood. I want to write out the density for this model (distribution) as an exponential family not distribution.

Comment: Doesn't $\eta(\theta)=\theta$, $T(y)=s(y)$, $h(y)=1$, and $A(\theta)=\log(c(\theta))$ do the job?

Comment: The exponential family is defined for the density not the distribution that's my concern.

Comment: No. _An_ exponential family is not only defined when the distributions involved have densitities with respect to the Lebesgue measure (i.e. they are absolutely continuous) but is also defined when they have densities with respect to the counting measure (i.e. they are discrete). For instance, the binomial distribution is an exponential family.

Comment: That classifies things, indeed it is a discrete distribution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density function is $P_\theta = p_\theta$ as it is a discrete distribution with respect to the counting measure. Then is it fairly easy to write it out as an exponential family.